# How to use an environment variable for length in a variable string substitution?

Tags: batch-file

I have the following code:

```
set name=James
echo %name:~0,4%
```

And it displays the first 4 letters of the variable: `Jame`.
But I'd like to insert a variable for the number of letters displayed which I can change with `set`. Something like this:

```
set num=3
set name=James
echo %name:~0,%num%%
```

The result should be showing the first `num` characters of string value of variable `name`.

Is there any method to get desired result?

Comment: Read about [delayedexpansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) `call echo %%name:~0,%num%%%`

Comment: Take a look on all answers posted on [How to substitute variable contents in a Windows batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4367297/)

Comment: Take a look at this answer: [How to expand two local variables inside a for loop in a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41122788).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add a layer of `%` around the echo statement and `call echo` it.

```
@echo off
set num=3
set name=James
call echo %%name:~0,%num%%%
```

or you can simply `enabledelayedexpansion`

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set num=3
set name=James
echo !name:~0,%num%!
```

For more help on `delayedexpansion` just run `setlocal /?` from cmdline.